# How to use expo speech inside webview inline html

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview, expo

Good day all, I'm trying to use expo speech to read text inside my webview.

Since I can't use javascript speech synthesis inside the webview, it makes it a bit difficult to crack.

Following the example from the expo documentation for speech, I have the code below, i'm also injecting the speech into the html with this:

${speak(utterance)};

The error is can't find variable utterance, I know why the error, but I don't know how to pass the text to the function speak.

Please check my code below.
Thanks

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import * as Speech from 'expo-speech';
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";

 export default function App() {
   const speak = (thingToSay) => {
     Speech.speak(thingToSay);
   };

   const html = `
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Epub Reader</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="toolbar">
        <button id=play></button>
        <button id=pause></button>
        <button id=stop></button>
      </div>
      <div id="area">
        <p id="readme">
         Content to be read
        </p>
      </div>
   <script>
     onload = function() {
       var playEle = document.querySelector('#play');
       var pauseEle = document.querySelector('#pause');
       var stopEle = document.querySelector('#stop');
       var flag = false;

       playEle.addEventListener('click', onClickPlay);
       pauseEle.addEventListener('click', onClickPause);
       stopEle.addEventListener('click', onClickStop);

       function onClickPlay() {
          if (!flag) {
            flag = true;
            utterance = document.getElementsById('readme').innerText;                
            ${speak(utterance)};
           }
        }
    }
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>`;

   return (
     <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <WebView source={{ html: html }} javaScriptEnabled={true} />
     </View>
   );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, so after a lot of research, I was able to come across webview's window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage and the onMessage prop from this blog: https://blog.logrocket.com/the-complete-guide-to-react-native-webview/

So all i needed to do was send a message back on button click from my html and pass the message to onMessage, which then calls the expo speech to read the sent back text.
Please check the code below for reference:

```
<script>
var playEle = document.querySelector('#play');
var pauseEle = document.querySelector('#pause');
var stopEle = document.querySelector('#stop');

playEle.addEventListener('click', onClickPlay);
pauseEle.addEventListener('click', onClickPause);
stopEle.addEventListener('click', onClickStop);

function onClickPlay() {
  window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.document.body.innerText);
}

function onClickPause() {
  window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage('pause');
}

function onClickStop() {
  window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage('stop');
}
```

and from the webview:

```
onMessage(m) {
  if(m.nativeEvent.data === "pause"){
    Speech.pause();
  } else if(m.nativeEvent.data === "stop"){
    Speech.stop();
  }else{
    Speech.speak(m.nativeEvent.data);
  }    
}

<WebView 
    source={{ html: html }} 
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    onMessage={m => this.onMessage(m)}
     />
```